# MySQL administration tool with serious foreign key management

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a recurrent problem with phpMyAdmin: its [relation view](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/relation#Relation_view) feature allows to create/drop foreign keys, but offers no control over the name of the constraint created.

Basically, it relies on default FK names like `UserAddress_ibfk_2`.

That becomes tricky when trying to version a database with SQL patches, when we have no control over the names of the constraints. Of course we can write all FK-related queries by hand, but that's like loosing a bit the point of using a tool like PMA.

Are you guys using good alternatives to phpMyAdmin that have a nice FK editor allowing to edit the names of the constraints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

- [Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

[image: Mysql Workbench]

- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com)

[image: navicat]

- [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com)

[image: sqlyog]

- [SQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com)

[image: SQL Maestro]

They are available in different version Windows, Linux or MAC

Comment: workbench seems the best one! I'll definitely use it

Comment: Whoa, nice post, thanks. TBH I was expecting a less *visual* tool, like just a dropdown for the relationship (as in PMA), and a textbox for the relation name. Looks like all tools are visual instead, any reason for that?

Comment: Oh, actually, just found what I need in MySQL workbench: **Object Browser** -> right click on a table name -> **Alter Table** -> **Foreign Keys** tab at the bottom of the screen!

Comment: MySQL workbench seem to be the best option for you, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's called [Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Very handy tool and available in different OS

Answer (score 0):

You can use object editors in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/table-designer.html#header). All objects editors are available in a free Express Edition.

Soon, flat-style object editors in next version.